# Suspend does not work on Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, suspend

Today I observed that suspend sometimes does not work properly in freshly installed Debian Jessie. After executing suspend (Alt + Shut Down button) the following message appears on black screen:

```
Loading, please wait...
```

The syslog is as follows. I kindly as for any suggestions.

```
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcaf80000-0xcafa2fff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcafa3000-0xcafdffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcafe0000-0xcaffffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcb000000-0xefffffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf3ffffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf4000000-0xfebfffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xffffffff]
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.160200] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xcaf80000-0xcafa2fff] (143360 bytes)
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    0.804259] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    3.909872] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    3.909878] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:5 present
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    3.909879] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    3.916677] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Jul 12 18:53:10 svarog kernel: [    3.916682] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're talking about suspend-to-RAM (aka sleep) rather than suspend-to-disk (aka hibernation), am I right?

Comment: @geewee Yes, I'm talking about suspend to RAM.