# lock screen & session suspension in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, freeze, suspend, debian-jessie, lock

I just read of an issue that seemed similar to mine, and as I cannot comment yet and my problem is different I will ask my question outright. the similar issue can be found here: 
[Suspend does not work on Debian Jessie](https://superuser.com/questions/939625/suspend-does-not-work-on-debian-jessie?rq=1)

My 'particular' issue is that I seem to not only be unable to suspend but lock the screen or hibernate as I did in Wheezy. I find it odd that such a basic function doesn't work in a 'stable' release. Namely I use the lock screen frequently. When I couldn't, for the first time, I didn't. My system was unresponsive when I came back 30 minutes later. I ended up for restarting. On the upside, I am aware the 'much' of what was in the state it was can be directly recovered due to journaling.

Even so, there are things that are immediately obvious  as not being how they were when I left. Frankly, I'm grateful that it's not more severe!

Still does anyone know the 'proper' way to report this bug? Also since my upgrade I don't yet have the anti-bug / bug tracking packages installed as of now. (My OWN fault, I know. If I did, I would be sending bug / craaash reports as I did in 'Wheezy'.)

also may be significant: KDE version changed to 4.14.2 (from 4.7.x I believe.) Dolphin also @ 4.14.2

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Did you know about [Linux & Unix SE?](http://unix.stackexchange.com) They've got some awesome Debian experts over there.

Comment: No. I am new here. Thank you for the link ;)